# Append an xml package object in to dictionary of python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

i am new to python, but some how i managed to learn and updating existing code.

The main goal of the python script which i am modifying is that to read an xml file, parse it and create a new json file. There are many python files which are used for parsing. I don't want to mention about every thing here. I will tell where i am getting an issue.

In the xml file,  there is an element which is having two same short names.

[image]

I want to append the elements of package in to a dictionary. So i am trying to use below python code,

```
    def extract(elem_type, attribute): (in this case, attribute is someip_service_instance_to_machine_mappings)
      for element in arxml_element.findall(elem_type.xpath, NS_MAPPING):
        getattr(parent_package, attribute).append(elem_type(element, parent_package))
        if attribute == 'someip_service_instance_to_machine_mappings':
            print("getting parent_package attribute")
            print(getattr(parent_package, attribute))
            print('\n')
```

according to above xml file, two short names are there for element SOMEIP-SERVICE-INSTANCE-TO-MACHINE-MAPPING. So, for-loop should be executed two times. which is executing (well and good). But when i print the attribute, loop 1st time : it is creating a dictionary and put the subpackage in to it. loop 2nd time : it is overwriting the existing subpackage. But i am expecting to append it. Below is the console output,

[image]

But if i change any of the short name *SomeipServiceInstanceToMachineMapping* to *CheckSomeipServiceInstanceToMachineMapping*. Then, it is appending correctly, Below is the console output after changing short name,

[image]

So my question is how append really works in this scenario? Is there any alternative for append, so that it can append though same short name.

Sorry for my stupid question :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, provide a standalone [minimal code and data to reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is required for the question to be accepted. Also it may be worth taking a minute to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Finally i found the problem, that attribute is dictionary, since key value is same, it updating the value. I think, we can close this. thanks @sophros